# How to automatically update nuget package dependency?

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuspec

I have have two packages \ projects "A" and "B". Where "B" is depending on "A" and use it as a reference.
When my build process in TFS is building "A" it's creating a nuget package from the nuspec and giving it a new version and put's it on my TFS private packages.

My problem is creating a well defined "B" package in every "B" build. In the "B.nuspec" file I write the version of the current "A" package:

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
        <dependency id="A" version="[1.0.0.3]" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

When ever I'm creating a new "A" package I'm updating the "B" project to use the new "A" release -> this also update the "packages.config" with the latest "A" version as expected. **The problem is that the build process of "B" create the "B" package from the nuspec file with the old dependency of "A"**. And I want it to use the "A" version from the "packages.config".

**Is there an automatic way to do it ?** (without manually changing the nuspec file every new version of "A") I thought of creating a small "Post-Build" process that read the version from the B-> "packages.config" and write it in "B.nuspec" file in the "A" dependency section. 
Does TFS support it in an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added a new post build event that trigger a script that's taking the version from the "packages.config" file and write them back to the nuspec file.

I upload the script and the post build event to my GIT for anyone who will need it.

https://github.com/avrum/NuspecAutoUpdate

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to auto-update your NuGet packages at build time [Cannot automatically update a NuGet package to the latest version during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027256/cannot-automatically-update-a-nuget-package-to-the-latest-version-during-build)

You need to add a new build step (such as powershell script) to your build process/ build definition to achieve it.

Comment: Well it's not that similar.. I added the post event script that I made to this question. Thanks